# ASP.NET MVC Entity - Scaffolding para mais de uma tabela simultaneamente

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, scaffold

Eu vi que um projeto ASP.NET MVC com C# tem 2 ferramentas mágicas que são os EntityFramework e o Scaffolding.
Com eles é possível em poucos minutos ter todas as funcionalidades de cadastro com no banco de dados. Basta trazer os modelos com o Entity e depois criar um controller com o scaffolding. Certo?
Bom isso é ótimo para cadastros diretos e simples. Mas e se eu quiser inserir em duas ou mais tabelas relacionadas simultaneamente no meu banco?
Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Tem como, com a mesma facilidade eu criar o INSERT/UPDATE, etc para essas 3 tabelas em um único formuário? Uma única página onde eu preencha todos os campos clique em 1 botão e tharam! Faço o insert nas 3 tabelas. Alguma coisa semelhante a:

```
SELECT dbo.Tab_Aluno.*, dbo.Tab_Pessoa_Fisica.*, dbo.Tab_Contato.*
FROM dbo.Tab_Pessoa_Fisica 
INNER JOIN dbo.Tab_Contato ON dbo.Tab_Pessoa_Fisica.Id_Contato = dbo.Tab_Contato.Id 
INNER JOIN dbo.Tab_Aluno ON dbo.Tab_Pessoa_Fisica.Id = dbo.Tab_Aluno.Id_Pessoa_Fisica
```

O modelo seria:

```
public class CadastroAluno
    {
        public int CPF { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Sexo { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataDeNascimento { get; set; }
        public string ContatoPrincipal { get; set; }
        public string TelefonePrincipal { get; set; }
        public string TelefoneSecundario { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Matricula { get; set; }
        public byte Foto { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataMatricula { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Tem sim, basicamente você salva o primeiro objeto recupera na própria instancia do entity framework o id do objeto salvo pegar seu id e usar para inseri no próximo insert e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Obrigado @MarconcilioSouza. Se entendi bem você sugere que eu crie manuamlente uma model com todos os campos que preciso. E quando o usuário clicar no botão salvar eu trato cada insert separadamente. Não éo que eu tinha em mente... mas pode resolver. Porém não entendi bem isso de "na própria instancia do entity framework o id do objeto salvo pegar seu id". Pode me dar um exemplo ou um link com algum artigo ou tutorial? presiso de alguma referencia dessa parte.

Comment: tem um bom exemplo aqui https://stackoverflow.com/a/42349763/2740371

Comment: se precisa de um exemplo poste seu modelo.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Por favor... me ajudaria muito. Meu modelo é exatamente essas três tabelas do post. Todos os campos exceto os Id's em Pessoa_Fisica e Contato. Tem uma tabela endereço, mas não precisa dela... (adicionei o modelo no post).

Comment: Isso ta mais para uma gabiara que para um modelo.

Comment: Kkkkkk! Desculpe a simplicidade, além de ser só um exemplo, eu sou iniciante em MVC. Estou tentando desenvolver minha primeira aplicação ainda... pegue leve.

Comment: OK, você importou seu banco de dados para sua aplicação usando o EF? ele gera o modelo para vc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que no seu modelo, na classe `PessoaFisica` tenha uma propriedade `Contato`, você pode adicionar tudo de uma vez, assim o `Entity` cuidará da transação para você, caso de erro em um dos `inserts`, não irá salvar nada, é mais seguro

```
public class Contato
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ContatoPricipal { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telefone_Principal { get; set; }
    public string Telefone_Secundario { get; set; }
}

public class PessoaFisica
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Cpf { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dt_Nascimento { get; set; }

    public int ContatoId { get; set; }
    public Contato Contato { get; set; }
}
```

Nessa etapa, ao criar o objeto de `PessoaFisica` já é adicionado o `Contato`, ai chamar o `SaveChanges()`, ambos objetos serão adicionados e já relacionados

```
using (var ctx = new SeuContexto())
{
    var pessoaF = new PessoaFisica
    {
        Cpf = "848.588.866-85",
        Dt_Nascimento = DateTime.Now,
        Contato = new Contato
        {
            ContatoPricipal = "sei la",
            Email = "seuemail@hotmail.com",
            Telefone_Principal = "99999999",
            Telefone_Secundario = "8888888",

        }
    };
    ctx.PessoaFisica.Add(pessoaF);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você salvaria seus dados assim;

```
using (var ctx = new stackoverflowEntities())
{
    var contato = new Contato();
    contato.ContatoPricipal = "sei la";
    contato.Email = "seuemail@hotmail.com";
    contato.Telefone_Principal = "99999999";
    contato.Telefone_Secundario = "8888888";

    ctx.Contato.Add(contato);
    ctx.SaveChanges();

    var pessoaF = new PessoaFisica();
    pessoaF.cpf = "848.588.866-85";
    pessoaF.Dt_Nascimento = DateTime.Now;
    pessoaF.ContatoId = contato.ContatoId; // aqui ta a magica .... 

    ctx.PessoaFisica.Add(pessoaF);
    ctx.SaveChanges();

}
```

Primeiro você salva o Contato e e depois de fazer o SaveChanges o contexto guarda o id que foi gerado então você usar para as tabela que tem dependência dela.

Comment: Muito obrigado meu amigo! Ajudou muio mesmo.

Comment: Precisa usar 2 `ctx.SaveChanges();` ? Só usar no final da linha que já faz os dois (Contato e PessoaFisica).